# How to get the values from a database randomly in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I had created a database and I want to get the records from database randomly . How can i get like that? Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What..? What kind of database?

Comment: sqlite, I had created a table which contains questions . I want to get those randomly not in sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get N_results random results at a time do:

```
NSString *yourQuery = @"SELECT * FROM sqlite_db ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT N_results";
```

or, with formatter:

```
NSString *yourQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM sqlite_db ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT %d", N_results];
```

Comment: Don't forget to Accept the answer if it's correct, this will help other users that will read the question.